# Como faço para verificar um login com sqlite3 + Python3?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, sqlite3

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
from random import randint
import os
import sqlite3
from tkinter import ttk

con = sqlite3.connect('BancoDeDadosCadastro.db')
cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BancoDeDadosCadastro (Nome VARCHAR, 
Turma VARCHAR, Turno VARCHAR, Matricula VARCHAR, Inscrição VARCHAR)')

root = Tk()
root.title('Cadastro Biblioteca Virtual')
root.geometry('700x500+0+0')
root.configure(background="green")
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)

'''Frame Topo'''
photo = PhotoImage(file = "topcadastro.png")
label = Label(root, image = photo)
label.pack(side=TOP)


'''Frame Direita'''
photo3 = PhotoImage(file = "side_right.png", width=480)
label3 = Label(root, image = photo3)
label3.pack(side=RIGHT)


lbl = Label(root, text="Cadastro / Login", bg="green", fg="white", font= 
("Century Gothic", 16, "bold"))
lbl.place(x=15, y=80)

def cad():
    clbl = Label(root, text="Cadastro para Biblioteca", font=("Century 
Gothic", 16, "bold"))
clbl.place(x=300, y=80)
clb2 = Label(root, text="Nome:", font=("Century Gothic", 10))
clb2.place(x=225, y=130)
centn = Entry(root, width=50)
centn.place(x=280, y=130)
clb3 = Label(root, text="Turma:", font=("Century Gothic", 10))
clb3.place(x=225, y=160)
cents = Entry(root, width=10)
cents.place(x=280, y=160)
clb4 = Label(root, text="Turno:", font=("Century Gothic", 10))
clb4.place(x=350, y=160)
centt = Entry(root, width=10)
centt.place(x=400, y=160)
clb5 = Label(root, text="Matrícula:", font=("Century Gothic", 10))
clb5.place(x=225, y=190)
centm = Entry(root, width=10)
centm.place(x=300, y=190)
albl = Label(root, text="Acesso para Biblioteca", font=("Century Gothic", 16, "bold"))
albl.place(x=300, y=270)
alb1 = Label(root, text="Matrícula:", font=("Century Gothic", 10))
alb1.place(x=225, y=325)
aentm = Entry(root, width=10)
aentm.place(x=300, y=325)
alb2 = Label(root, text="Nº da Inscrição:", font=("Century Gothic", 10))
alb2.place(x=370, y=325)
aentn = Entry(root, width=4)
aentn.place(x=480, y=325)

def shw():
    aentm['show'] = "●"
    aentn ["show"] = "●"
    avs = Label(root, text="O botao 'ⓘ' torna a senha oculta", font=("Century Gothic", 12))
    avs.place(x=225, y=450)
bts = Button(root, text="ⓘ", font=("Arial Black", 12), command=shw)
bts.place(x=520, y=320)

def cd():
    a = centn.get()
    b = cents.get()
    c = centt.get()
    d = centm.get()
    e = randint(0, 300)
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Confirmação", message=("Cadastrado \n Nº de Inscrição:" , e))
    messagebox.showinfo(title="Confirmação", message=("nome: ", a, "Turma: ", b, "Turno: ", c, "Matricula: ", d))
    print("nome: ", a, "Turma: ", b, "Turno: ", c, "Matricula: ", d, "Nº de Inscrição:" , e)
    centn.delete(0, 'end')
    cents.delete(0, 'end')
    centt.delete(0, 'end')
    centm.delete(0, 'end')
    cur.execute('INSERT INTO BancoDeDadosCadastro VALUES(?,?,?,?,?)',
            (a,b,c,d,e))
    con.commit()

cbt = Button(root, text="Cadastrar", font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), command=cd)
cbt.place(x=300, y=225)

def logar():
    x = aentm.get()
    y = aentn.get()
    try:
        cursor = cur.execute('SELECT Matricula AND Inscrição FROM BancoDeDadosCadastro')

        for row in cursor:
            if x in row:
                pas = cur.execute('SELECT Inscrição FROM BancoDeDadosCadastro WHERE Matricula')
                if y in pas:
                    messagebox.showinfo(title="Prosseguindo...", message=("Acesso Confirmado\n Bem Vindo"))
                    pas.fetclone()
                    os.startfile(r"GerenciadorLivros.py")
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo(title="Prosseguindo...", message=("Senha Incorreta!"))

        messagebox.showinfo(title="Prosseguindo...", message=("Login Incorreto! Se voce ainda nao se registrou, favor registar."))
    finally:
        return

abt = Button(root, text="Acessar", font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), command=logar)
abt.place(x=300, y=375)

bt2 = Button(root, text="Cadastrar", font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), command=cad)
bt2.place(x=100, y=200)
bt = Button(root, text="Acessar", font=("Arial", 13, "bold"), command=cad)
bt.place(x=15, y=200)

photo4 = PhotoImage(file = "liceun.png")
label4 = Label(root, image = photo4)
label4.place(x=5, y=275)




root.mainloop()
```

Bem estou tentando um sistema de cadastro, eu já conseguir fazer todos os botões e banco de dados, agora quero saber como faço para verificar o login do usuário.

No login e solicitado Matricula e Numero de inscrição, todas as informações já estão indo para o banco de dados que criei, estou tentando encontrar uma forma de autenticar o usuário que fizer o login, Para apenas ele conseguir fazer o login se as informações já estiverem no banco de dados, caso não estejam recuse o login.
 Estou tentando encontrar uma forma de fazer isso, mais não estou conseguindo, alguém pode me ajudar e dar algumas dicas ?

Comment: Alguém consegue responder ?

Comment: Editei e coloquei todo o código.

Comment: Não entendi qual seu problema. Precisa apenas fazer uma consulta de `matricula` e `numero de inscrição` passando o valor das entradas, se retornar diferente de `None` ok, senão login incorreto

Comment: Como estou sem tempo pra analisar seu código e responder, segue um [link](https://www.sourcecodester.com/tutorials/python/11351/python-simple-login-application.html) que pode ser útil

Comment: Sim nessa parte que estou com problemas, não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar, quando coloco a inscrição e a matricula correta aparece apenas ''Login Incorreto! Se voce ainda nao se registrou, favor registar.'' Vou ver o link que você envio e tentar arrumar o problema, obrigado.

Comment: Já conseguir conseguir fazer, obrigado pelas informações.

Comment: Israel, se possível responda a pergunta com a solução para o seu problema, caso alguém tenha o mesmo problema já vai ajudar ;)